# Why do page speed sites list CSS as a render blocking resource?

Tags: css, google-pagespeed

CSS was designed to cascade layout changes and is not render blocking, is it? so why do page speed tests say CSS can be rendered blocking?

Comment: CSS resources are totally render blocking.  This is to stop flash-of-unstyling-content (FOUC) happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mix of html and `<style>` tags inside the `<body>` the render will stop and process the CSS - so for example if JavaScript is running when the browser encounters a set of CSS in style tag(s) the engine needs to apply that style and create a flow from that.

To re-state:
Once a `<style>` tag is encountered inside the `<body>` everything stops and the CSSOM is rebuilt and re-applied to all existing rendered (painted) content. What is CSSOM? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model

Comment: Note in HTML 4.01 and prior the `<style>` tag is required to be in the `<head>` as stated in the HTML standards